# Isomorphism between $SO_2\tilde{\times}\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $O_2$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, orthogonal-matrices, semidirect-product

This is the exercise 23.10 p. 135 of Groups and symmetry of Armstrong :

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and write $G \tilde{\times}\mathbb{Z}_2 $ for the semidirect product $G\rtimes_\phi\mathbb{Z}_2$, where $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \text{Aut}(G)$ sends $1$ to $x\rightarrow x^{-1}$.
>
> [...]
>
> Prove that $O_2 \cong SO_2 \tilde{\times} \mathbb{Z}_2 $.

My idea was to take the morphism :
$$ \Phi(A, k) = (-1)^k A$$
But it seem to be wrong. Any hints ?

Comment: "it seems to be wrong" — what makes you think that? Show what you've got.

Comment: Am I just not getting semi-direct products, or is this group really weird? It seems like $(A,1)*(A,1) = (I, 0)$, so all elements of the form $(A,1)$ are unipotent? 

Also OP, because of this example, you can see that your proposed isomorphism is not a morphism of groups!

Comment: @RichardJensen yes that's what I thought. This is not a morphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful tool in questions about semi-direct product is the [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma#Non-abelian_groups).

Consider an exact sequence
$$1\to SO(n) \hookrightarrow O(n)\xrightarrow{\det} O(1)  \to 1.$$

There is a homomorphism $p\colon O(1)\to O(n)$ given by $p(-1)=R$, where $R\in O(n)$ is any *reflection*. Obviously $\det \circ p = \mathrm{id}_{O(1)}$, so the splitting lemma guarantees us that $O(n) \simeq O(1) \rtimes SO(n)$.

---

Let's be more explicit for $n=2$. Take
$$R = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \in O(2)$$
to be the reflection. We need an action $\phi\colon O(1) \to \mathrm{Aut}(SO(2))$ (which can be easily reconstructed from the splitting lemma):

$$\phi(1)(B) := A^{-1}BA = B^{-1}.$$

Alternatively, you can start from this map $\phi$, construct the semi-direct product [as usual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product#Inner_and_outer_semidirect_products), and then explicitly show that you get $O(2)$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. We need to construct a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \rtimes SO(2)$ to $O(2)$ where the map from $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ to $Aut(SO(2))$ is allready given. I get that $O(1) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but It seems like you are redefining what the semi-direct product should be.

Comment: The upper part shows how to get the map using a splitting lemma, which is a powerful tool (works for all $n$ in the same way), but quite abstract. In the bottom I translate this to fit the OP's definition of the semi-direct product (see also the link given, why this equivalent to other definitions).